# Tracing Oracle Host Program

Tags: oracle, trace

I have a Oracle host program which is currently having high runtime issue. 
The underlying prog file is submitting sql queries via multiple sql and shell scripts.

The difficulty we are facing is not to tune the sql but to identify which queries are the top runtime consumers as enabling trace for the host program doesn't result in any trace file.
Is there any way we can take trace of all the sql queries which are run from the sql files and shell scripts?

I have tried taking session level traces of the sql files but it is not replicating the runtime issue.

Please let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: Check out `v$session`, `v$sql`, `v$sqlstats` and related views. You can also use the Entprise Manager/Grid Control to monitor the session (and statements)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I appreciate your help, but can you please elaborate on how can I use these views to get the traces. This program is not having any oracle_process_id, that means no trace is being generated when i enable tracing at the program level.

Comment: Those view show the *current* activity in the system regardless whether your session has tracing enabled or not. They tell you which session is running which SQL statement and what kind of load that generated. Monitoring and tuning an Oracle database is not something that can not be taught with a single answer. The manual is a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Instead of manually qeurying these v$ views when our host program is running to find out the query which is taking long do we have any utility or any other way to enable tracing for host program so that we can get all the queries in a single trace file like we get in case of package based oracle program.

Comment: One option is to get the session level traces for each of the underlying sql scripts in the .prog file.